# unity per fragment shading fail

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I wrote two shaders one for per-vertex shading and the other per-fragment shading both simulating point light diffuse lighting, both shaders do work without popping up error, but the rendered model of the per-frag shader appears to have the same result as the per-vertex one, I mean the the per-frag smoothing effect between vertices looks just 100 percent the same as the per-vertex linear interpolated result.

so,,,, what goes wrong with my codes or did I misunderstood something, and is there any difference between texcoord set 0 1 2 3 4 ?

per-vertex shader:

```
    Shader "Custom/neo2" {
Properties {

    _LightPosX("lightposx",float) = 14
    _LightPosY("lightposy",float) = 14
    _LightPosZ("lightposz",float) = 14

}
SubShader {

    Pass{

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        float _LightPosX; 
        float _LightPosY;
        float _LightPosZ; 

        struct tex{
            float4 tex0:TEXCOORD0;
            float4 tex1:TEXCOORD1;
        };

        struct col{
            float4 col;
        };


        col vert(float4 pos:POSITION,out float4 oPos:SV_POSITION,float3 normal:Normal){
            oPos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,pos);
            col c;
            float3 normalDir = normalize((mul(_Object2World,float4(normal,0))).xyz);
            float3 lightDir = normalize(float4(_LightPosX,_LightPosY,_LightPosZ,1) - mul(_Object2World,pos));
            c.col = float4(1,1,1,1)*dot(normalDir,lightDir);
            return c;

        }

        float4 frag(col c):COLOR{
            return c.col;
        } 

        ENDCG






    }


} 
FallBack "Diffuse"
```

}

per-fragment shader:

```
    Shader "Custom/neo3" {
Properties {
    _LightPosX("lightposx",float) = 14
    _LightPosY("lightposy",float) = 14
    _LightPosZ("lightposz",float) = 14

}
SubShader {

    Pass{

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        float _LightPosX; 
        float _LightPosY;
        float _LightPosZ; 

        struct tex{
            float4 tex0:TEXCOORD0;
            float4 tex1:TEXCOORD1;
        };


        tex vert(float4 pos:POSITION,out float4 oPos:SV_POSITION,float3 normal:Normal){
            oPos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,pos);
            tex t;
            t.tex0 = mul(_Object2World,pos);
            t.tex1= normalize(mul(_Object2World,float4(normal,0)));
            return t;

        }

        float4 frag(tex t):COLOR{
            float3 lightDir = normalize(float3(_LightPosX,_LightPosY,_LightPosZ) - t.tex0);

            float4 col = float4(1,1,1,1)*dot(t.tex1,lightDir);
            return col;




        } 

        ENDCG






    }


} 
FallBack "Diffuse"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences between the texcoords.

How the lightning looks is mostly dependent on the normal you use to do the calculation. In both cases you pre calculate the normal i the vertex and thus are given the same result since you use the same normal for the whole triangle.

If you instead do the calculation in the fragment you get one normal for each pixel and are thus given a much smoother result.

The per-pixel shader

```
tex vert(float4 pos:POSITION,out float4 oPos:SV_POSITION,float3 normal:Normal)
{
    oPos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,pos);
    tex t;
    t.tex0 = mul(_Object2World,pos);
    t.tex1 = float4(normal,0);

    return t;
}

float4 frag(tex t):COLOR
{
    float3 lightDir = normalize(float3(_LightPosX,_LightPosY,_LightPosZ) - t.tex0);

    float4 normal = normalize(mul(_Object2World,float4(t.tex1,0)));
    float4 col = float4(1,1,1,1)*dot(normal, lightDir);
    return col;
}
```